# three.js uv maps with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, blender

this is my first time using three.js or 3d modeling, so forgive me if what i am about to ask sounds stupid or too obvious

so i have a 3d model t-shirt with the uv map like this
[image: Text]

and then i have succesfully loaded it to three.js using gltf loader, and can change its texture using canvas texture + fabric.js

but it looks like the entire uv maps is in 1 canvas like this
[image]

but what i tried to achieve is to separate the uv maps to another canvas, something similar with this
[image]

so how do i achieve it? and one more, why is the uv map flipped upside down when loaded to three.js?

Comment: I see no PHP in the question so removed the tag @Nanu.

Comment: @hakre alright thank you, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: do u find the solutions?

Comment: yes it's actually pretty easy, i just cheese my way through it